# "Warning: Do not place Android context classes in static fields; this is a memory leak (and also breaks Instant Run)"

Tags: java, android, memory-leaks, android-volley

Similar question have been [asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37709918/warning-do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39868001/do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory-leak) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37894622/do-not-place-android-context-classes-in-static-fields-this-is-a-memory-leak-a) but the context  is quite different from this and moreover the [code that gave from this error](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/requestqueue.html#singleton) is written by the makers of Android and Android Studio.

This is the code:

```
public class MySingleton {
    private static MySingleton mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;
    private static Context mCtx;

    private MySingleton(Context context) {
        mCtx = context;
        mRequestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(mRequestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
            private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                    cache = new LruCache<String, Bitmap>(20);

            @Override
            public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                return cache.get(url);
            }

            @Override
            public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                cache.put(url, bitmap);
            }
        });
    }

    public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        if (mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new MySingleton(context);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(mCtx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return mImageLoader;
    }
}
```

The lines giving the warning are:

```
private static MySingleton mInstance;
private static Context mCtx;
```

Now if I remove the `static` keyword, change `public static synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context...` to `public synchronized MySingleton getInstance(Context...` the error disappers but another problem comes up.

I use `MySingleton` in RecyclerView. So this line

`@Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ImageLoader imageLoader = MySingleton.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();`

tells me

> Non-static method 'getInstance(android.content.Context)' cannot be refrenced from a static context.

Please anybody knows how to fix this?

Comment: How is this different from the other questions you linked?

Comment: The code ant it's application

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39840818/android-googles-contradiction-on-singleton-pattern/39841446#39841446

Comment: This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37532046/6444297) worked for me.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I found the solution to this in the [answer to a similar question answered by CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39841446/6181476)

I quote

> The quoted Lint warning is not complaining about creating singletons.
>   It is complaining about creating singletons holding a reference to an
>   arbitrary Context, as that could be something like an Activity.
>   Hopefully, by changing mContext = context to mContext =
>   context.getApplicationContext(), you will get rid of that warning
>   (though it is possible that this still breaks Instant Run — I cannot
>   really comment on that).
>
> Creating singletons is fine, so long as you do so very carefully, to
>   avoid memory leaks (e.g., holding an indefinite static reference to an
>   Activity).

So Google is not actually contracting itself. To fix this, if `this.getApplicationContext` is supplied as a parameter for the context, then there will be no memory leak.

So in essence, ignore the warning and supply `this.getApplicationContext` as a parameter for the context.

Comment: I already have `mContext = context.getApplicationContext()` warning is still there!

Comment: Please can you show the full code? I'll be in a better position to help you if I can see the code.

Comment: I can confirm, this does not remove the lint warning.  I don't think changing Context to getApplicationContext will work since it is still return an object of Context type.

Comment: @Pellet Yes the lint warning will still be there but since you're using  `context.getApplicationContext()` there's no actual memory leak. If your goal is to fix the memory leak, this is the solution... except you have a better alternative.

Comment: @Max Yes the lint warning will still be there. Just ignore it.

Comment: @Ozuf An alternative could be to remove the static method from the class and get an instance of the singleton instead via a dependency injection framework.  This could be overkill for your implementation though :)

Comment: @X09 What do you think about Application class instead of Context in the constructor?

Comment: To suppress warning use @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")

Answer (score 4):

I ended up putting this in AppController which has no warning.

```
public class AppController extends MultiDexApplication {

    public static Context getContext() {
        return mInstance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    private static AppController mInstance;

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mInstance = this;

    }
}
```

So whenever you need it just call `AppController.getContext()`

Comment: This leads to the same error in my case. `mInstance` is now the problematic field. And why do you need `getInstance()`?

Comment: mInstance is null in design time in xml layout with custom views, i know it is scarce somehow, but i lost preview in some xml with custom views :(

Answer (score 0):

I simply removed the static reference to context and works with no errors:

```java
public class RequestQueueSingleton {

    private RequestQueue requestQueue;
    private final ImageLoader imageLoader;
    private final Context ctx;

    private RequestQueueSingleton(Context context) {
        ctx = context;
        requestQueue = getRequestQueue();

        imageLoader = new ImageLoader(requestQueue,
                new ImageLoader.ImageCache() {
                    private final LruCache<String, Bitmap>
                            cache = new LruCache<>(20);

                    @Override
                    public Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
                        return cache.get(url);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void putBitmap(String url, Bitmap bitmap) {
                        cache.put(url, bitmap);
                    }
                });
    }

    public static synchronized RequestQueueSingleton getInstance(Context context) {
        RequestQueueSingleton instance;
        instance = new RequestQueueSingleton(context);
        return instance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (requestQueue == null) {
            // getApplicationContext() is key, it keeps you from leaking the
            // Activity or BroadcastReceiver if someone passes one in.
            requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ctx.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return requestQueue;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        return imageLoader;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

This was my solution.  There is no need to hold a static reference when you're just returning the instance of the RequestQueue?

```
public class VolleyRequestQueue {

    private static VolleyRequestQueue mInstance;
    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;

    private VolleyRequestQueue() {

    }

    public static synchronized VolleyRequestQueue getInstance() {
        if(mInstance == null) {
            mInstance = new VolleyRequestQueue();
        }
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue(Context context) {
        if(mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context.getApplicationContext());
        }
        return mRequestQueue;
    }
}
```